# Horizontal to vertical menu, on browser window resize

Tags: html, css

Say I have the following list in html:

```
<ul>
   <li>Program</li>
   <li>Platser</li>
   <li>System</li>
</ul>
```

Which is styled as follows:

```
li
{       
   float: left;
   padding: 10px;
}
```

This looks something like this:

[image]

When I resize the browser window, and the border touches the edge of the last li, this element jumps down as expected:

[image]

Though, the desired behavior I am after would be like this:

[image]

When the last element is touched by the browser border, the whole menu becomes vertical. My question is how to do this with CSS?

Answer (score 3):

You need to look into CSS3 media queries/responsive web design. Tons of results on google and on SO, but here's [one](http://webdesignerwall.com/tutorials/responsive-design-with-css3-media-queries).

```
@media screen and (max-width: 200px) {
// do something here, change the behavior of your list
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could CSS3 media queries to remove the float:left when the width of the screen is small enough.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/Media_queries

Answer (score 0):

you can set the width or min-width attribute in CSS for the ul element to prevent it to be cropped if you resize the page

Answer (score 0):

Use CSS3 media query and specify different css rules for different width of the browser window.